# Problem in displaying pdf file after decryption in Flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, aes, syncfusion

I am working on a Flutter application which involves getting a pdf file from internet, encrypt and store it in application file directory and retrieving, decrypting it for displaying in app.
I am using https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt and **Syncfusion pdf viewer** for this purpose.
But on decrypting and displaying file I am getting

```
ArgumentError{Invalid argument (position): Invalid Position:-1}
```

at SfPdfViewer when running in debug mode.
The code is :

```
`SfPdfViewer.network( 
          widget.file!.link!, 
          key: _pdfViewerKey, 
          onDocumentLoaded: (PdfDocumentLoadedDetails details) async { 
        // final Directory tempPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); 
        // _tempFile = await File('${tempPath.path}/${widget.file!.title}.pdf') 
        //     .writeAsBytes( await details.document.save()); 
      }):FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
        future: getFileBytes(),
        builder:(context,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData)
          {
            logger.i("Snapshot Data is ${snapshot.data}");
            return SfPdfViewer.memory(snapshot.data!,key: _pdfViewerKey, );
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasData)
          {
            snapshot.printError();
            return Text('Error');
          }
          else
          {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        }
      )
      );
    
  }
  Future<Uint8List> getFileBytes() async
  {
    return await fileController.getDecryptedFile(name: widget.file!.title!);
    
  }`
```

Download, encrypt and decrypt methods are:

```
    Future<void> downloadFile({required Files file})async
  {
    
    logger.e("Link of file to be downloaded is ${file.link}");
    Response response=await download(url: file.link!);
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filesDirectory = await Directory('${directory.path}/files').create(recursive: true);
    

    String filePath='${filesDirectory.path}/${file.title!}.aes';

   
    logger.i("Length of key is ${key.length}");
    final encryptor=Encrypter(AES(key,padding: null));
    logger.i("Unencrypted bytes: ${response.data}");
    final encryptedBytes = encryptor.encryptBytes(response.data,iv: iv,);
    final decryptedBytes = encryptor.decryptBytes(encryptedBytes,iv: iv,associatedData: encryptedBytes.bytes);
    logger.i("encrypted bytes: ${encryptedBytes}");
    final encryptedFile=File(filePath);
    encryptedFile.writeAsBytesSync(encryptedBytes.bytes);
    changeDownloadStatus(true);
    
    
  }



  Future<dynamic> download({required String url}) async
{
  try{
    String token=url.substring(url.indexOf("token")+7,url.indexOf("_gl"));
    String alt=url.substring( url.indexOf("alt=")+5,url.indexOf("token="));
    String gl=url.substring(url.indexOf("_gl=")+5);
    Map<String,String> query={
      "token":token,
      "alt":alt,
      "_gl":gl
    };
    Response response =await Dio().get(url.substring(0,url.indexOf("?")),options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
            followRedirects: false,contentType: "application/pdf"),queryParameters: query);
    logger.i(response.data);

    changeDownloadStatus(true);
    return response;
  }
  on Exception catch(e)
  {
    logger.e(e.toString());
  }
}

Future<Uint8List> getDecryptedFile({required String name}) async
{
     final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filesDirectory = Directory('${directory.path}/files');
    String filePath='${filesDirectory.path}/$name.aes';
    File encryptedfile=File(filePath);
    bool isPresent=await encryptedfile.exists();
    logger.i("File at path $filePath is present $isPresent");
   
    
      Uint8List encryptedBytes=encryptedfile.readAsBytesSync();
      logger.i("encrypted bytes: ${encryptedBytes}");
      
      // Decrypt the file
      
    final encryptor=Encrypter(AES(key,padding: null));
    final decryptedBytes=encryptor.decryptBytes(Encrypted(encryptedBytes),iv: iv,associatedData: encryptedBytes);

    return Uint8List.fromList(decryptedBytes);
    
   
}
```

Key and Iv are obtained as:

```
 final iv=IV.fromLength(16);
    final key=Key.fromSecureRandom(32);
```

I am getting a list in logs with the same data of unencrypted bytes and decrypted bytes.
Also when using default padding in encryptor object, I get **Invalid or corrupted padding at decryptBytes method.**
Where is the issue?

Comment: Please simplify your question to demonstrate a minimal example that shows the issue - probably a plain Dart program. (We don't need to see your FutureBuilder and Dio code as that's not relevant to the encryption. Nor indeed is the PDF display code.) As an aside, you should reformat your Dart code using dartfmt so that it follows the community standards for Dart.

Answer (score 0):

We have reviewed the provided sample and created a similar application that encrypts and decrypts files using the package you shared via https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt. We have successfully loaded the decrypted bytes in SfPdfViewer, and it properly displayed the PDF document on our end. I have attached the code snippet of the sample for your reference. Please try this and let us know if you are still facing any issues. If you are, kindly share the modified code sample that reproduces the issue. This will help us provide a prompt solution as soon as possible.

**Code Snippet:**

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Syncfusion PDF Viewer Demo',
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

/// Represents Homepage for Navigation
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();
  Uint8List? _documentBytes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadPdfDocument();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
        ),
        body: _documentBytes != null
            ? SfPdfViewer.memory(_documentBytes!)
            : Container());
  }

  /// Handling the encryption, decryption and load the document in SfPDfViewer.
  Future<void> loadPdfDocument() async {
    const url =
        'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final fileBytes = response.bodyBytes;
      final key = encrypt.Key.fromSecureRandom(32);
      final iv = encrypt.IV.fromSecureRandom(16);
      final encrypter =
          encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.ctr));

      // Encrypt the file
      final encryptedBytes = encrypter.encryptBytes(
        fileBytes,
        iv: iv,
      );
      // Decrypt the file
      final decryptedBytes = encrypter.decryptBytes(encryptedBytes, iv: iv);
      // For loading the decrypted bytes in SfPdfViewer.
      _documentBytes = Uint8List.fromList(decryptedBytes);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```